# Onelogin login error: "Response not found"

Tags: php, yii, onelogin, scim

I'm using SCIM Provisioner with SAML (Enterprise Schema) app. I got the following error when try to login to my website using the app:

> Error : OneLogin_Saml2_Error:-SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding

How can I fix this?

Comment: seems like your are not making a POST request . can u show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems unrelated to SCIM - Try looking into OneLogin's SAML guide first then focus on the SCIM portion of your application: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml

Ultimately the comment above is right - You should be posting your SAML response and the OneLogin toolkits should help you get your SAML right.